# Using mysql with oracle sql developer

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have configured mysql db with oracle sql developer version 4.0. But create table, create database all the options for mysql databases are disabled.

I was able to create a new database only by running the `create database` command. Can any tell me a workaround for this. Is it not possible to create tables using the GUI?

Screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: Didn't you specify a database when we create a MySQL connection in SQL Developer?  Can you not create tables in that database?

Comment: well there are several existing dbs, I need to create a new one, for that I can't do it via GUI.

Comment: ya thanks, I've moved to MySql Workbench

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MySQL support in Oracle SQL Developer is for migrating MySQL databases to Oracle.

If you want that type of GUI support, you should be using the MySQL Workbench product.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to use Oracle SQL developer for MySQL DB.

All you need to do is to use following convension:

```
DB_name.TABLE_name
SELECT * FROM movies.directors
DB_name = movies
TABLE_name = directors
```